# How can I call this api using retrofit only for login user

Tags: android, retrofit2

I can't access login method from my interface class in login activity.

Here is my api> `http://localhost/AdminaService/AdminaService.svc/Verify_User_And_Password_For_login/{PUSER_ID}/{PPASSWORD}/{PUSER_SESSION_ID}/{PIPADDRESS}/{PAPPLICATION_ID}`

Api interface

```
public interface Api {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Verify_User_And_Password_For_login")
    Call<LoginResponse>login(
            @Path("PUSER_ID") String user_id,
             @Path("PPASSWORD") String Ppassword
    );



}
```

"Login activity"

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText edit_user, edit_pass;

    private Button btn_login;
    private static final String Base_url="http://localhost/AdminaService/AdminaService.svc/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        if (!isConnected(LoginActivity.this)) buildDialog(LoginActivity.this).show();

        edit_user = findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
        edit_pass = findViewById(R.id.editText_password);

        btn_login=findViewById(R.id.button_signIn);

        String U_id=edit_user.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass=edit_pass.getText().toString().trim();

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(Base_url)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

                Call<LoginResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                        .getInstance()
                        .getApi()
                        .login(User_id,Ppassword);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call,Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                        //After Login
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call,Throwable t) {

                    }
                });




            }
        });

    }





    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

  }
```

[image]

Comment: do you know what `localhost` means?

Comment: instead of localhost specify IP address of the machine where your server runs

Comment: Please don't use plaintext passwords :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a typo. Your variables are `U_id` and `pass`, not `User_id` and `Ppassword`

Comment: give your full login url for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Verify_User_And_Password_For_login")
Call<LoginResponse>login(
        @Path("PUSER_ID") String user_id,
         @Path("PPASSWORD") String Ppassword
);
```

You may not pass login parameters as pathparams, Use @Field or @Query instead

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Verify_User_And_Password_For_login")
Call<LoginResponse>login(
        @Field("PUSER_ID") String user_id,
         @Field("PPASSWORD") String Ppassword
);
```

refer : https://square.github.io/retrofit/